# Java client for AppFabric Cache?

Tags: java, .net, azure, appfabric

Is there any java library available to use [Windows Azure AppFabric Caching](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/features/caching/) features?

I want to put some string in the AppFabric cache from a java application and retrieve it from a .Net application (and the other way around too).

[AppFabric SDK for Java Developers](http://jdotnetservices.sourceforge.net/Home.html) provides classes to access AppFabric [Access Control](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/features/accesscontrol/) and [Service Bus](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/features/servicebus/), but it doesn't provide classes to access [Caching](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/features/caching/) features.

Thanks in advance

Comment: AppFabric is primarily for web applications.  If you need to interface between java and .Net, have you considered memcached?

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm looking for a way to interface with a .Net web app already using AppFabric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got two options here:-

1. Reproduce in java, from a client perspective the mechanism that the appfabric client uses to interact with the cache cluster. You'll need to sniff out the tcp messages that the appfabric client wcf creates and reproduce them.
2. Expose a mechanism from your ASP.NET app that wraps the call to the .net AppFabric client and make your Java app call the wrapper. The wrapper could expose a SOAP or restful interface - you could provide CRUD cache methods.

If I were you I'd, do the latter. I think it'd be faster to implement and easier to test.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be impossible to have a native client because of tcp transport and serialization (deserializing in java ...). A WCF service using a basicHttpBinding can solve your problem. The problem is that is will need a separate hosting and it will not as fast as AppFabric native client.